# Can I add a Trigger based on change of a particular cell?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that is currently set to run onEdit. Ideally, I'd like the script to run ONLY when someone makes a change to cell B26 of the sheet in question.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes.  Put an event argument into the arguments section of the function: `onEdit(e)`  Then use `e.range` to get the cell that was edited, then put a condition check into the function to run code only if the cell is B26.

Comment: Hi @SandyGood thanks for the info. I do have some (foundational) experience with JS and about 2 weeks worth of GAS. I follow what you are saying but would struggle to act based on this info alone. Could you "hold my hand" a little here and flesh out a bit how this would look? I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is code taken directly from the documentation:

```
function onEdit(e){
  // Set a comment on the edited cell to indicate when it was changed
  var range = e.range;
  range.setNote('Last modified: ' + new Date());
}
```

It already has `e.range` in it.  All you need to do is add an `if` statement, and get the cell address of the range:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var cellAddress,cellAddressToTestFor;

  cellAddressToTestFor = 'B26';

  // Get cell edited - If it's B6 then do something
  cellAddress = e.range.getA1Notation();
  Logger.log('cellAddress: ' + cellAddress);

  if (cellAddress === cellAddressToTestFor) {
    //To Do - Code here if cell edited is correct
    Logger.log('the check worked!');
  };
}
```

Add that code.  Edit a cell, then VIEW the LOGS.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Looks simple enough except something seems off. When I view logs I get "range: Range". e.range is not a string then? Not sure how to convert to something I can compare to in the if()? So right now range is "range" not B26. I tried using getCell(1,1) on range but similar result too.

Comment: I added the `getA1Notation()` method.  See updated answer.  See if that works.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for this. I will likely draw on this many times in the future too