# Hide/Unhide Rows Excluding Specific Row

Tags: google-apps-script

I am on basics of appscript and learning it progressively with the help of this community. Any help on below will be appreciated.

I am trying to design a script which hides and unhides rows on change of selection and for that I got a solution from question posted at below link.

[Google Sheet Hide/Unhide Rows Using Appscrit Unhide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72908877/google-sheet-hide-unhide-rows-using-appscrit-unhide)

Below is the code given in above link

```
function onEdit(e) {
const sh = e.range.getSheet();
const rg = e.source.getRangeByName("NamedRange1");
const sr = rg.getRow();
const sc = rg.getColumn();
const er = sr + rg.getHeight() - 1;
const ec = sc + rg.getWidth() - 1;
if (sh.getName() == "Sheet3" && e.range.columnStart >= sc && e.range.columnStart <= ec 
&& e.range.rowStart >= sr && e.range.rowStart <= er && e.value) {
//e.source.toast("Flag1")
const sh2 = e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
const vs = sh2.getDataRange().getValues();
vs.forEach((r, i) => {
if (r.every(e => e == '')) {
if (e.value == "A") {
sh2.hideRows(i + 1);
} else {
sh2.showRows(i + 1)
}
}
});
}
}
```

The code is given proper result but I want a bit modification in the same. The unhide command of the code unhides all the rows of the sheet, however I want the code to unhide all the rows except first row of the sheet.

Any help on above will really be appreciated.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `The unhide command of the code unhides all the rows of the sheet, however I want the code to unhide all the rows except first row of the sheet.`, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
vs.forEach((r, i) => {
if (r.every(e => e == '')) {
if (e.value == "A") {
sh2.hideRows(i + 1);
} else {
sh2.showRows(i + 1)
}
}
});
```

#### To:

```
vs.forEach((r, i) => {
  if (r.every(f => f == '')) {
    if (e.value == "A") {
      sh2.hideRows(i + 1);
    } else if (i > 1) {
      sh2.showRows(i + 1);
    }
  }
});
```

- When this is reflected in your script, `sh2.showRows(i + 1)` is run when `e.value != "A"` and `i > 1`. By this, the 1st row is skipped.
- And also, in the case of `r.every(e => e == '')`, `e` has already been used with the event object. So, I changed it to `f`.

Comment: @ Tanaike it works great... thanks for the wonderful and super fast solution....